# receiving ElementNotVisibleException when element should be visible to webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to have selenium click on links, which are within li elements.  This is happening inside a while loop.  The clicks are working until I reach an li which is below the level of the Firefox window.  If I manually scroll down in the Firefox webdriver window before selenium attempts the click, the click will work without error.

Here is the  java code I'm using for the click.  Menu_item_module is an int which increases by 1 each time the loop runs to move down the list.  The webelement below references the li element.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("digitalVellum_dijit_MenuListItem_" + menu_item_module)).click();
```

Here is a code snippet containing one of the li elements from the page in question.

```
<li id="digitalVellum_dijit_MenuListItem_11" class="dijitLayoutContainer dijitContainer menuListItem level1 item-22 closed dijitLayoutContainer-child dijitLayoutContainer-dijitLayoutContainer" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:click" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" widgetid="digitalVellum_dijit_MenuListItem_11">
<a href="#" data-dojo-attach-point="_link" tabindex="0">
<span class="expander" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_toggleState"></span>
<span class="label">Overview</span>
<div class="clearoutfloats"> </div>
</a>
<ul id="digitalVellum_dijit_MenuList_2" class="mainMenu dijitLayoutContainer dijitContainer dijitLayoutContainer-child dijitLayoutContainer-dijitLayoutContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" widgetid="digitalVellum_dijit_MenuList_2">
</li>
```

I have tried to have selenium scroll by using the following code.

```
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsx.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,100)", "");
```

This appears to have no effect.  I think that may be because the scroll area is a frame, not the entire page.  Regardless, I didn't think I should need to scroll at all.  I thought webdriver will scroll automatically when necessary to select an element.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve Archibald

Comment: If the element is in a frame, you'll need to use `driver.switchTo().frame("frameIdentifier")` before you'll be able to access elements in that frame.

Comment: Might be helpful to maximise browser window first using `driver.manage().window.maximize();` and then try the click.

Comment: As @Faiz mentioned, maximize the page before clicking the links. I had a very similar issue, where the driver will automatically scroll down to the link, but won't click it. Because my page was not maximized due to which there was a horizontal scroll bar. Every time when the browser scrolled down to the link, it was trying to click on the link but was actually clicking on the horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the element isn't in view(hidden), you can execute javascript on it:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsx.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

where `element` is the element you want to click on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait for elements before you click especially when you are doing it in a loop. Like others suggested, also try maximizing the window. Probably that will help WebDriver find the co-ordinates of the WebElement accurately, however I am not 100% sure. But I believe that you need WebDriverWait. Give this a try,

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300/*seconds*/);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.bbc.com/");
for (int menu_item_module = 0; menu_item_module < 10; menu_item_module++) {
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
                        .id("digitalVellum_dijit_MenuListItem_"
                                +menu_item_module)));
            element.click();
}
```